# ReactJS Add new row to Table

Tags: reactjs, html-table

I create Table dynamicaly:
In component Table I set the default values of table in json:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: [
            {'Date': '', 'Operation': '', 'Amount': '', 'Item_of_expenditure': '', 'Balance': ''}
        ]
    };
}
```

Then use it to render table:

```
   render() {
    return (
        <div className={styles}>
            <table>
                <thead>
                <tr>{this.getHeader()}</tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {this.getRowsData()}
                </tbody>
                <button onClick={this.addRow}>
                    Add new row
                </button>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}
```

This is a methods realization:

```
getKeys = function () {
    return Object.keys(this.state.data[0]);
};

getHeader = function () {
    var keys = this.getKeys();
    return keys.map((key, index) => {
        return <th key={key}>{key.toLowerCase()}</th>
    })
};

getRowsData = function () {
    var items = this.state.data;
    var keys = this.getKeys();
    return items.map((row, index) => {
        return <tr key={index}><RenderRow key={index} data={row} keys={keys}/></tr>
    })
};
```

And now I try to add new row, using this method:

```
 addRow = function () {
    let newRows = this.state.data.push({'Date': '', 'Operation': '', 'Amount': '', 'Item_of_expenditure': '', 'Balance': ''});
    this.setState({data: newRows});
};
```

But when I try it, I receive the following error: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
in

```
    return Object.keys(this.state.data[0]);
```

Indeed, after I push a new object to "data", I see, that "data" not containts any elements. Although before that it contained 1 element: {'Date': '', 'Operation': '', 'Amount': '', 'Item_of_expenditure': '', 'Balance': ''}

Answer (score 1):

This is the wrong in your function. Push will return you the values that pushed into the array,

```
addRow = () => {
    let existingRows = this.state.data;
    existingRows.push({'Date': '', 'Operation': '', 'Amount': '', 'Item_of_expenditure': '', 'Balance': ''});
    this.setState({ data: existingRows });
};
```

If You wish to use arrow function for addRow the below will not be needed! Or if you wish to use the normal function you are using you have to change the button onClick as below,

```
addRow = function () {
     let existingRows = this.state.data;
     existingRows.push({ 'Date': '', 'Operation': '', 'Amount': '', 'Item_of_expenditure': '', 'Balance': '' });
     this.setState({ data: existingRows });
};

<button onClick={() => this.addRow()}>
    Add new row
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of `newRows` will be `{'Date': '', 'Operation': '', 'Amount': '', 'Item_of_expenditure': '', 'Balance': ''}` which you are setting as state instead it should be an array.

So what you can do is:-

```
     let rowsData = this.state.data;
     existingRows.push({ 'Date': '', 'Operation': '', 'Amount': '', 'Item_of_expenditure': '', 'Balance': '' });
     this.setState({ data: rowsData });
```